# How to validate initramfs built in kernel image?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, initramfs

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and I am trying to enable initramfs in my system.

I configured the kernel as follows,

```
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE="/home/t/target_rootfs"
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_ROOT_UID=0
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_ROOT_GID=0
CONFIG_RD_GZIP=y
CONFIG_RD_BZIP2=y
....
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM is not set
```

And the `target_rootfs` has followings,

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Dec 13 17:47 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 dev
drwxr-xr-x 6 t t 4096 Dec 13 20:24 etc
drwxr-xr-x 3 t t 4096 Dec 13 17:47 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 t t    3 Oct 23 14:59 lib32 -> lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 t t   11 Oct 23 15:01 linuxrc -> bin/busybox
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 opt
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 proc
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 root
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 run
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Sep 19 18:58 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 sys
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 5 t t 4096 Dec 13 17:47 usr
drwxr-xr-x 3 t t 4096 Jun 28 06:23 var
```

The kernel command line is

```
console=ttyS0,115200 init=/linuxrc ubi.mtd=5 root=ubi0:rootfs rootfstype=ubifs rw flashtype=nand
```

With above settings, the system can boot to `shell` in the nand rootfs!
Now to validate if `initramfs` built in the kernel is working (or being used), I did followings.

1. I tried to erase the rootfs partition in MTD5 in FLASH

Hoping to stop system booting at `initramfs`, but I got kernel panic as follows,

```
[    0.715989] Kernel panic - not syncing: write error
[    0.720880] Rebooting in 10 seconds..
```

2. Then in the `target_rootfs` I created `init` by `ln -sf bin/busybox init`, and rebuilt the kernel (keeping the rootfs undeployed), I got followings,

```
[    5.266031] VFS: Cannot open root device "ubi0:rootfs" or unknown-block(0,0): error -19
[    5.274324] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    5.282987] 1f00            1024 mtdblock0
[    5.282992]  (driver?)
[    5.289753] 1f01           65536 mtdblock1
[    5.289759]  (driver?)
[    5.296540] 1f02          195584 mtdblock2
[    5.296545]  (driver?)
[    5.303320] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    5.311876] Rebooting in 10 seconds..
```

So, how to validate the `initramfs` built in the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer part of the question by reading [kernel document of ramfs rootfs initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)

And it says,

> ### What is initramfs?
>
> All 2.6 Linux kernels contain a gzipped "cpio" format archive, which is
> extracted into rootfs when the kernel boots up.  After extracting, the kernel
> checks to see if rootfs contains a file "init", and if so it executes it as PID 1.  If found, this init process is responsible for bringing the system the
> rest of the way up, including locating and mounting the real root device (if
> any).  If rootfs does not contain an init program after the embedded cpio
> archive is extracted into it, the kernel will fall through to the older code
> to locate and mount a root partition, then exec some variant of /sbin/init
> out of that.

So in my 1st test, kernel did NOT find the `init` in initramfs, so it followed the old path.  In my 2nd test, kernel find the `init` in initramfs, and started it to run and did initialization.

Here is the log I got from 2nd test after deployed rootfs.

```
[    5.352428] Warning: unable to open an initial console.
[    5.357833] ====== kernel_init_freeable, 1541, 80a7fe00 (/init)
[    5.364712] ====== kernel_init_freeable, 1544
[    5.370661] UBIFS (ubi0:0): Mounting in unauthenticated mode
[    5.376636] UBIFS (ubi0:0): background thread "ubifs_bgt0_0" started, PID 913
[    5.403187] UBIFS (ubi0:0): start fixing up free space
[    9.912861] UBIFS (ubi0:0): free space fixup complete
[    9.934491] UBIFS (ubi0:0): UBIFS: mounted UBI device 0, volume 0, name "rootfs"
[    9.942191] UBIFS (ubi0:0): LEB size: 126976 bytes (124 KiB), min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048 bytes/2048 bytes
[    9.952459] UBIFS (ubi0:0): FS size: 189702144 bytes (180 MiB, 1494 LEBs), journal size 9023488 bytes (8 MiB, 72 LEBs)
[    9.963525] UBIFS (ubi0:0): reserved for root: 0 bytes (0 KiB)
[    9.969555] UBIFS (ubi0:0): media format: w4/r0 (latest is w5/r0), UUID B61B21A3-D917-436E-986D-091B195DF275, small LPT model
[    9.981938] UBIFS (ubi0:0): full atime support is enabled.
[    9.987664] VFS: Mounted root (ubifs filesystem) on device 0:14.
[    9.994297] devtmpfs: mounted
[    9.997393] ====== kernel_init_freeable, 1550
[   10.009306] Freeing unused kernel memory: 17812K
[   10.014107] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
[   10.020789] ====== kernel_init, 1434, 00000000 (none)
[   10.026726] ====== kernel_init, 1450, 80007c67 (/linuxrc)
[   10.033039] Run /linuxrc as init process
.....
```

I added `printk` in `init/main.c`, and it seemed that firstly kernel ran `/init` from initramfs, then ran `/linuxrc` as specified in kernel command line.

So now the question is who mounted the 2nd rootfs and started the `/linuxrc`? My assumption is it is `/init`, but kernel logs showed it is `kernel` did that......

And how to stop the system in `initramfs`?